# Warning when using sparse categorical values with LightGBM

Tags: categorical-data, categorical-encoding, lightgbm

When training a LightGBM model with `lgbm.train`, I get the following warning:

> [LightGBM] [Warning] Met categorical feature which contains sparse values. Consider renumbering to consecutive integers started from zero

The reason is that I have a column, specified as categorical, that contains the following integers:

> [1015, 1033, 1128, 1398, 1541, 1673, 1677]

In the documentation at [lightgbm.train.html](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.train.html) it says:

> *"All values in categorical features will be cast to int32 and thus should be less than int32 max value (2147483647). Large values could be memory consuming. Consider using consecutive integers starting from zero."*

My values are not particularly large. The *"considering using consecutive integers starting from zero"* seems to be a suggestion. What happens if they do not? How does the sparseness affect the performance of LightGBM? Another categorical column of the dataset has the values

> [1, 3, 4]

and it does not cause the same warning.

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Right, I was contemplating if Cross Validated was the right forum for the question as it more focused on the he LightGBM implementation. Perhaps I should re-iterate the question in another forum. It does however also touch on the underlying algorithm for handling categorical values, but again, main focus was on LightGBM's warning.